# Devexpress FindPanel background color

Tags: c#, find, devexpress, panel, backcolor

I want to notify the user that there is some text typed in the `FindPanel` of a devexpress `GridControl`. Say he changes a filter and sees no results (due to his previous search via the `FindPanel`).

One solution would be to clear the text in the `FindPanel` if the `ColumnFilterChanged` event of the considered view is raised. But what I want to do is change the `BackColor` of the `FindPanel` which I couldn't find (there is no appearance customization in the `OptionsFind` property of the view).

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this type of issue and if there is a way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be impossible to set the BackColor of the FindPanel. I had the same issue with the FilterPanel, the BackColor is retrieved by the currently applied Style. 
Here are some threads on the topic from the DevExpress Forum:

[Find Panel Appearance](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q382244)

[How to customize the Find Panel layout](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2806)

[BackColor of the FindPanel when we use LookAndFeel](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q311518)

Go for the first approach and use

```
gridView.ApplyFindFilter(string.Empty);
```

when needed.

Comment: That's what I thought. Hope they'll work on this issue for their next releases. Thanks for the answer @JohnThompson !